# Spring+JPA/Hibernate questions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I have working code that saves entity to DB with using EJB+JPA+Hibernate. Now I need to change EJB to Spring.

Below is my simplified manager class.

```
//@Stateless - changed to @Service
@Service
public class Manager {

    //@EJB - changed to Autowired
    @Autowired
    private ClientDao clientDao;

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        clientDao.addClient(client);
    }
}
```

Below is my DAO class.

```
//@Stateless - changed to @Repository
@Repository
public class JpaClientDao implements ClientDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ClientsService")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        em.persist(client);
    }
}
```

Below is persistence.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

  <persistence-unit name="ClientsService" transaction-type = "JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>myJtaDatabase</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.entity.Client</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

resoures.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <Resource id="myJtaDatabase" type="DataSource">
        JdbcDriver org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
        JdbcUrl jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/ClientDB
        UserName test
        Password 123456
        validationQuery = SELECT 1
        JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
</resources>
```

Questions. 
1) When I used EJB, I had Container-Managed Transactions. Who should manage transactions with using Spring? 
2) Do I need to necessarily use Spring Framework transaction management? Is there any alternatives? 
I found some examples like this http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/java-persistence-example-with-spring-jpa2-and-hibernate/, and I cant undestand is code below spring specific or it suits for me.

```
    <!-- ************ JPA configuration *********** -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />  
    <bean id="transactionManager"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"     value="classpath:config/persistence-demo.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="restDemoDS" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.codingpedia.demo.*" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

3) Do I need to edit Java code or should my steps be in xml configuration?

Any useful links are encouraged.

Comment: where you are declaring transaction management before in your EJB CMT code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) When I used EJB, I had Container-Managed Transactions. Who should
>   manage transactions with using Spring?

Answer : Spring provides container managed transaction support too (See JTA transaction manager , sample oracle [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jta-spring-article-128573.pdf)) and also application managed transaction (which means your application can declaratively/programatically manage the transactions with minimal effort by using Spring transaction API ) . [See Spring transaction doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-motivation)

> 2) Do I need to necessarily use Spring Framework transaction
>   management? Is there any alternatives?

Answer: If spring framework is not managing your transactions, then your container will need to manage them..you have alternatives of any Java EE JTA implementations like opensource JBossTS or enterprise JTA implementations Oracle-WebLogicJtaTransactionManager or IBM-WebSphereUowTransactionManager, you can find how to use them in the same point 1 spring documentation. You can even have your own transaction manager implemented.

But if you are already using Spring framework why not benefit from spring transaction management with plenty of configurations possible, (Spring + Hibernate transaction manager, Spring + JPAContainerManager, Spring+ JTAContainerManager etc..)

> 3) Do I need to edit Java code or should my steps be in xml
>   configuration?

Answer: Your transcation manager xml config seems fine to use a JpaTransactionManager, now you can initiate transactions in your service layer java code by annotating @Transactional which typically handles your service methods to participate in a transaction according to the configured transaction manager.

```
@Service
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public class Manager {
```